# Simultaneous clicks on an image

Tags: android, multi-touch

For my current android project I am trying to allow multiple clicks on one (large) image which will lets say give you a point. So far I have the onClick set in XML, which only works for one finger at a time (if one finger is down holding the image a second finger cannot click it). Could someone explain what I would have to do to enable this feature or point me to relevent code.

I checked in layout XML if there is any direct option to enable this but found nothing, I have also tried searching for this question on Google / Stack but only got "pinch to zoom" answers or answers in different programming languages.

Thank you!

Comment: problem related to multitouch, there is a very good article by Google Engineer http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to set **OnTouchListener** on the view (ImageView may be) for handling multiple touches.

Here is a simple explanation of implementing multi-touch on a view.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);
    int pointerIndex = MotionEventCompat.getActionIndex(event);
    int x = (int)MotionEventCompat.getX(event,pointerIndex);
    int y = (int)MotionEventCompat.getY(event,pointerIndex);

    switch(action)
    {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        //
        // First finger was touched. Set "pointerIndex" to some value (lets say 0 or -1)
        // Save "pointerIndex" corresponding to this touched object.
        //
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
        //
        // More finger touched when first finger is already touched.
        // Save "pointerIndex" corresponding to this touched object.
        //
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        //
        // Finger with "pointerIndex" was moved.
        //
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        //
        // The first touched finger went off.
        //
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        //
        // Finger with "pointerIndex" went off (other than first finger)
        //
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Good Luck. :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, been fighting this for over 30 minutes and I'm kind of stuck. I understand that pointerIndex is incremented with each additional finger but for some reason I'm not so good at controlling it. Would you know what I would have to do to increment a variable let's say i++ with each tap on the screen even if there are fingers already on it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You don't need another variable than the 'pointerIndex'. The pointer index is generated automatically by the event. BUT, as for the first pointer (first touched finger) you will have to ASSUME a value for pointerIndex (lets say -1). As we know that the event will never generate '-1' as pointer index, so at ACTION_POINTER_UP, if we read '-1', it will be the first pointer.